# How to do file transfer inside ssh command line?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, sftp, aix

I have to transfer a file from server A to B and then needs to trigger a script at Server B. Server B is a Load balance server which will redirect you either Server B1 or B2 that we dont know.

I have achieved this as below.

```
sftp user@Server
put file
exit
```

then executing the below code to trigger the target script

```
ssh user@Server "script.sh"
```

But the problem here is as I said it is a load balance server, Sometimes I am putting file in one server and the script get triggers in another server. How to overcome this problem?

I am thinking some solutions like below

```
ssh user@server "Command for sftp; sh script.sh"
```

(i.e) in the same server call if I put and triggers it will not give me the above mentioned problem. How can I do sftp inside ssh connection? Otherwise any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're just copying a file up and then executing a script, and it can't happen as two separate commands you can do:

```
gzip -c srcfile | ssh user@remote 'gunzip -c >destfile; script.sh'
```

This `gzip`s srcfile, sends it through ssh to the remote end, `gunzip`s it on that side, then executes `script.sh`.

If you want more than one file, you can use `tar` rather than gzip:

```
tar czf - <srcfiles> | ssh user@remote 'tar xzf -; script.sh'
```

if you want to get the results back from the remote end and they're files, you can just replicate the tar after the script…

```
tar czf - <srcfiles> | ssh user@remote 'tar xzf -; script.sh; tar czf - <remotedatafiles>' | tar xzf -
```

i.e. create a new pipe from ssh back to the local environment. This only works if `script.sh` doesn't generate any output. If it generates output, you have to redirect it, for example to /dev/null in order to prevent it messing up the tar:

```
tar czf - <srcfiles> | ssh user@remote 'tar xzf -; script.sh >/dev/null; tar czf - <remotedatafiles>' | tar xzf -
```

Comment: Crystal Clear. Thanks.

Comment: If I want to transfer all files in a directory how can I change the above code? gzip -r zips all files individually not as a single.

Comment: In that case you use something like tar - `tar czf - <files/dir> | ssh user@host 'tar xzf -; script.sh`. If you want to specify a destination directory add `-C <destdir>` e.g. `tar xzf - -C <destdir>`

Comment: Thanks, it is fine now. Another question is after executing the script at remote site I need to pull some data from there. Is it possible within the same connection?

Comment: if the script doesn't produce any output, then you can simply do: `tar czf - <srcfiles> | ssh user@remote 'tar xzf -; script.sh; tar czf - <remotedatafiles>' | tar xzf -`. I've updated the answer with more details

Answer (score 0):

You can use scp command first to upload your file and then call remote command via ssh.

`$ scp filename user@machine:/path/to/file && ssh user@machine 'bash -s' < script.sh`

This example about uploading a local file, but there is no a problem to run it on server A.

Comment: When we do scp fist it is first attempt to server, when we do ssh in the second time it is another connection. So it is not always goes to the same server.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a fifo (Named Pipe) on the server, and start a program that tries to read from it. The program will block, it won't eat any CPU.

From sftp try to write the pipe -- you will fail, indeed, but the listening program will run, and check for uploaded files.

```
# ls -l /home/inp/alertme
prw------- 1 inp system 0 Mar 27 16:05 /home/inp/alertme
# date; cat /home/inp/alertme; date
Wed Jun 24 12:07:20 CEST 2015
<waiting for 'put'>
Wed Jun 24 12:08:19 CEST 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

transfer testing with tar gzip compression, ssh default compression. using PV for as pipe meter (apt-get install pv)
testing on some site folder where is about 80k small images, total size of folder about 1.9Gb
Using non-standart ssh-port 2204

1) tar gzip, no ssh compression

```
tar cpfz - site.com|pv -b -a -t|ssh -p 2204 -o cipher=none root@removeip "tar xfz - -C /destination/"
```

pv meter started from 4Mb/sec, degradated down to 1.2MB/sec at end. PV shows about 1.3Gb transfered bytes (1.9GB total size of folder)

2) tar nozip, ssh compression:

```
tar cpf - site.com|pv -b -a -t|ssh -p 2204 root@removeip "tar xf - -C /destination/"
```

pv meter started from 8-9Mb/sec, degradated down to 1.8Mb/sec at end